# Passing props from child to parent class component in React

Tags: reactjs

My child class is ChangeProps and parent is ParentClass

```
class ChangeProps extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.childname}</h2>
        <button onClick={()=>this.props.onNameChange()}>Change</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class ParentClass extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      name:'parent name'
    }
    this.onChange=this.onChange(this);
  }

  onChange=(newName)=> 
  {   
    this.setState({ name: newName });
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <ChangeProps childname={this.state.name} onNameChange={this.onChange}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the button to change the state, name doesn't change. I got the below error:
`TypeError: this.props.onNameChange is not a function`

Comment: Two changes: 1) Remove `this.onChange = this.onChange(this)` and 2) change `onClick={()=>this.props.onNameChange()}` to `onClick={this.props.onNameChange}`

Answer (score 2):

since you are using arrow functions you dont have to explicitly define the scope so commenting the line `this.onChange=this.onChange(this);` would work

```
class ParentClass extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          name:'parent name'
        }
        //this.onChange=this.onChange(this);//comment this line
      }
      onChange=(newName)=> 
      {   
        this.setState({ name: newName });
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <ChangeProps childname={this.state.name} onNameChange={this.onChange}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
}
```

Here is the working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q3kuek)

---

Or else

```
class ParentClass extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          name:'parent name'
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);//bind the function to the scope
      }
      onChange(newName) {//keep this as regular function
        this.setState({ name: newName });
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <ChangeProps childname={this.state.name} onNameChange={this.onChange}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
}
```

Comment: like this `<button onClick={()=>this.props.onNameChange('helllo')}>Change</button>`

Comment: tha state name on parent is now changes. so can we access the previous value of the state name ?

Comment: from where do you want access the old value?

Comment: i want access it on child component

Comment: even after you changing the value?

Comment: yes.is that possible? I just want to know that can we access the previous value, because have seen in some docs that previous vales are accessed by prevState.statename

Comment: nope, that is when you tring to set a new state using `setSatate`,when you want to access prevState to set a new state then there's a best practice to use callback inside `setState`, EX: `this.setState((prevState) => return {statename: prevState.statename + 1})`